# Organization of operator hierarchy of '+=' and '++'?

Tags: java, operators

I am a little confused about the following short code snippet, why is the result not 4, but 3?

```
int i = 1;
i += ++i;
System.out.println(i);
```

What I thought is:

1. Calculate the right side, `++i`, `i` is 2 then;
2. Calculate the `+=`, `i = i + 2`, at this time point, I thought `i` should be 4 now, but the result is 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Calculate the right side, ++i

No, that's not the first step.

The first step is to evaluate the original value of the *left* side. Then evaluate the right side. Sum them, and assign the result to the variable.

So

```
i += ++i;
```

is broadly equivalent to

```
i = i + (++i);
```

In particular, from [JLS 15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), emphasis mine:

> - Otherwise, **the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, **the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation indicated by the compound assignment operator**. If this operation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.

Comment: I think the ++ operator has a higher precedence than +=, why is the ++ operation not done first?

Comment: @WenhuCao: Precedence is about grouping. It's precedence that means `a + b * c` is treated as `a + (b * c)` rather than `(a + b) * c` - but `a` would still be evaluated first.

Comment: OK, let me digest for a while... Thanks a lot anyway:)

Answer (score 5):

The [Evaluation Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) is as:

```
i += ++i;

=> i = i + ++i;  
=> i = 1 + ++i;
=> i = 1 + 2;
```

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.